# GAE ftp_nlist() does not work

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Google App Engine PHP. When trying to use `ftp_nlist()` I get the following error:

> ftp_nlist(): Unable to create temporary file. Check permissions in temporary files directory.

It works on the development server as long as it's a frontend module. It does not work on production at all.

`get_system_tmp_dir()` returns vfs://root/temp. I've tried using `putenv("TMPDIR=" . get_system_tmp_dir());` before using any ftp functions as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just received word from the folks at Google that this is an internal issue within GAE's PHP runtime. A fix *should* be released within the next few weeks.